# Is it possible to check if npm is installed in the system using composer?

Tags: php, dependencies, npm, composer-php

I am writing a composer file. In this file I am checking whether *imagick* and *mysql* is installed or not. I also want to make sure whether npm is installed in the system or not. Is it possible? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [exec](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) to run something like npm -v and check the exit code.

```
exec('npm -v', $foo, $exitCode);

if ($exitCode === 0) {
  echo 'npm is installed!';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/local/bin/bash

if hash npm 2>/dev/null; then
    echo "Npm est installé"
else
    echo "Npm n'est pas installé"
fi
```

(This works because hash is a bash builtin for which

> The return status is true unless a name is not found

(Source: man bash))